# Counting fields from related tables

Tags: mysql

There are three tables that are related to each other.
I want to count ***customers.userid*** whithout duplicates from three related tables, but I get stuck every time.

these are my tables:

customers table:

| Id (FOREIGN key) | userid | fname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 | a |
| 2 | 12 | b |
| 3 | 13 | c |
| 4 | 14 | d |
| 5 | 14 | e |
| 6 | 15 | f |
| 7 | 15 | g |

customerscategories table:

| Customerid (FOREIGN key) | Catid (FOREIGN key) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 99 |
| 2 | 99 |
| 3 | 100 |
| 4 | 101 |
| 5 | 101 |
| 6 | 101 |
| 7 | 101 |

Categories table:

| Id | pcatid | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 99 | a |
| 2 | 99 | b |
| 3 | 100 | c |
| 4 | 101 | d |
| 5 | 101 | e |
| 6 | 101 | f |
| 7 | 101 | g |

except 2 first line of my code the rest work fine and result is:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bF1Re.jpg

but when i add ***select DISTINCT COUNT customers.userid
FROM*** mysql gives error 1064.
my code is:

```
select DISTINCT COUNT sub2.userid
FROM (
    SELECT sub2.pcatid, customers.userid
FROM (
    
    
SELECT Subquery.id, categories.pcatid ,categories.name
FROM (
SELECT customers.id, customerscategories.catid
FROM customers
INNER JOIN customerscategories on customers.id=customerscategories.adid
) as Subquery
INNER JOIN categories on Subquery.catid = categories.id
    
) as sub2 
INNER JOIN customers on sub2.id = customers.id)
WHERE sub2.pcatid=101;
```

and i expect this count number:
2

Comment: Count is a function

Comment: What is the right query?

Comment: Use count as a function. The syntax error will go away, but the rest is totally unclear what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax of count is:

> Count(*expression*)

So your code should be:

```
select count(DISTINCT customers.userid) FROM ....
```

Hope this help.